# Division between two lists and store the results in a list NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I have two lists with same length. And I want to divide them one by one. The first element in the first list is divided by the first element in the second list. And store the results in a new list. 
Let's say there are two list named *a* and *b*. And the new list for results is *c*.
I have something like this now:

```
foreach a b [[element-a element-b] -> element-a / element-b]
```

But it doesn't work. And how do I store the results in *c*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is not `foreach`, it's [`map`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map)!

```
to demo
  let list-a [ 4 12 30 ]
  let list-b [ 2  3  5 ]  
  print (map [ [a b] -> a / b ] list-a list-b) ; long syntax
  print (map / list-a list-b) ; concise syntax
end
```

Whenever you want to create a new list out of one or more lists, `map` is most likely the best solution. It's one of the most useful primitives in NetLogo.

Note that you need parentheses around the expression because you're passing more than one list to `map`.